# Relationships with inheritance properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
public class abstract Animal
{
    [Key]
    public string AnimalId { get; set; }
    public Zoo Zoo { get; set; }
    public string ZooId { get; set; }    
}

public class Giraffe : Animal { }
public class Elephant : Animal { }

public class Zoo 
{
    [Key]
    public string ZooId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Giraffe> Giraffes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Elephant> Elephants { get; set; }
}

//OnModelCreating
builder.Entity<Animal>.HasOne(a => a.Zoo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.ZooId); //1
builder.Entity<Giraffe>.HasOne(g => g.Zoo).WithMany(z => Giraffes).HasForeignKey(g => g.ZooId); //2
builder.Entity<Elephant>.HasOne(g => g.Zoo).WithMany(z => Elephants ).HasForeignKey(g => g.ZooId); //3

//DbSets
public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
public DbSet<Giraffe> Giraffes { get; set; } 
public DbSet<Elephant> Elephants { get; set; } 
public DbSet<Zoo> Zoos { get; set; }
```

I get error here:

> The navigation property 'Giraffes' cannot be added to the entity type
>   'Zoo' because its CLR type ICollection Giraffe> does not match the
>   expected CLR type 'Animal'.

It could be fixed by replace **1** of

```
builder.Entity<Animal>.Ignore(a => a.Zoo); 
//both 2 and 3 here
```

However it has a very harsh side effect:

```
await DbContextInstance.Animals.Include(a => a.Zoo).ToListAsync(); //Include throws ArgumentNullException
```

Can I resolve it without uniting both `ICollection<Giraffe> Giraffes` and `ICollection<Elephant> Elephants` to `ICollection<Animal> Animals`?

Comment: Can you please explain why using `ICollection<Animal>` is not a viable solution? Your abstract class clearly states that *any* animal has a `Zoo`.

Comment: Shorty - you can't. `ICollection<Animal>` is the right (and only) way. And use `OfType` when you need to get filtered set.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev thank, I think now it is the best solution for my scenario

Comment: First error is because you are using same navigation property to configure 3 different relationships. Second error because you are trying to include a navigation defined on derived type from base type query. So either you need to query separately or combine into all base type navigations as @IvanStoev suggested.